# Pandas/Python - comparing two columns for matches not in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data:

[image]

I wanted to compare A and B for matches not by row but rather search A0 if it is in column B and so on. Moreover, I wanted to ignore the .AX in column A because it would not find any matches in column B anyway.

I used this, but it matches values row by row and it returns False or True. I would like to print the matches in a new Column C:

```
    df3['match'] = df3.A == df3.B
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, this question is about comparing two columns to check if the 3-letter combinations match.

So, I would approach this in the following manner:

```
# Extract the 3-letter combinations from column a
df3["a normalised"] = df3["a"].str[:3]

# Then check if what is in `a normalised` is in column b 

b_matches = list(df3[df3[“b”].isin(list(df3[“a normalised”]))][“b”].unique())
df3.loc[:, "match"] = False

b_match_idx = df3[df3["a normalised"].isin(b_matches)].index

df3.at[np.array(b_match_idx),"match"] = True
```

EDIT: The parentheses have now been resolved. Also the .loc warning can now be mitigated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I got a KeyError for column b. I guess there is a parenthesis problem in b_matches = list but I can't make it work. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Steven, my parentheses weren't correct, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. I got 2 issues there: 1) It matches values "row by row" but it doesn't match, for example, A0 with B1, B2 and so on, meaning all values in A column are matched with all values in B column, I don't know if I explained correctly. 2) The script works but it returns also this: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: So what the code should do is that it set the values in the ```match``` column to be true if any of the values in the ```a normalised``` exists in the b column. It doesn't tell you which ones it matches with. Do you want me to include this in the implementation?
The warning comes about from the ```df3["match"]``` line. I will properly edit this again when I hear from you.

Comment: Yes, it can print a new column with matches found when it finds whatever match between the 2 columns. Thanks again.

Comment: I got the same error after the edit. I guess the error comes from this df3[df3["a normalised"].isin(b_matches)]["match"] = True

Comment: Got you thank you for the comment @Steven, this should now have resolved that, I have obtained the indices where the 3-letter combinations from column ```a normalised``` exist in ```column b``` and then used the .at() method to convert those indices which do 'match' to become True.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!